# Does Keras nested models share attributes?

Tags: python, keras, generative

I am trying to use Keras to implement GANs(Generative Adversial Network). For the non-saturating game, the loss for the generator looks like this:[image: Generator loss]

I am considering to implement this as a nested model in Keras which looks like this:

```
def generator_containing_discriminator(generator, discriminator):
     model = Sequential()
     model.add(generator)
     discriminator.trainable = False
     model.add(discriminator)
     return model
```

I wonder **whether the discriminator in this nested model shares parameters with the one I passed in.**

Another but more general question is that it would be reassuring to me if I can check the attributes(such as object id or object attributes like trainable) in each model, how can I check this in Keras?